# Can I determine whether Data is English or Chinese language?

Tags: java

Is it possible to determine whether data is in English or Chinese?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is for example possible using statistical methods. English language has a very distinctive distribution of characters that appear at all, and a very distinctive distribution of what characters appear following another character (that would be called a level-1 model).

If 'e' is the most common symbol, it is very unlikely that the language is *not* something of European origin.

It may also be possible rather trivially (but maybe not 100% reliably) to do such a distinction by looking at Unicode character values (converting between character sets if necessary). If there are characters with a Unicode value greater than 127, English is somewhat unlikely (note that there are symbols like € though).
If there are many characters with Unicode values in the thousands, east Asian languages become more and more likely, with codes > 65535 being guaranteed to be Chinese.

Comment: It's very interesting to think of all the ways we identify/differentiate languages. You could start with all the languages you're concerned about starting with the same score, and then adding or subtracting as per Damon's rules, and then picking the top of the list, with a calculated likelihood.

Comment: A logical extension of this would be to compress an English text with a standard order-1 arithmetic (or huffman) compressor and save the model. Then compress the unknown text with the same compressor. If it is English, the summed error between the models should be close to zero (or, the dot product, if you regard the models as vectors, should be close to 1).

Answer (score 5):

My idea is to calculate the average position of the characters in the Unicode table. Since Chinese characters are located after ASCII (e.g. after value 127) you could easily determine if the text is English or Chinese.

edit: Basically the same Damon added. >_>